# Is there a name for the problem of representing state twice and then getting out of sync?

Tags: solid, anti-patterns

I have a system that has configurable state values, like BoxCount, "Number of Visible Boxes on the screen".   If I am using some heavyweight set of patterns (like MVC) that enforce the creation of multiplicities of classes, and if I follow design patterns, I often find the case where some tree of objects exists like this:

- CModelBox = a model class dealing with some box count
- CViewBox = a view class dealing with showing the count of boxes
- CControllerBox = a controller class dealing with some box count.

If each of the above had a field (a member variable) called Count, and that one fact (how many boxes?) is repeated in the implementation, and then somehow has to be "updated" in every which way, is there a name for this problem? Is it known by some name, as an anti-pattern, or by some other formal name that might help me do some research on how people identify, and remediate these problems in their application designs?

The very specific problem I observe most often is that any time you have two fields instead of one, you CAN have a difference, and then the question is, does the difference have meaning, or is it an accident. If it's an accidental (and permanent rather than temporary) difference, a failure to keep things in sync, then it's a lurking bug.

Update: I suspect that people who build systems according to "SOLID" OOP principles might have a definitive name for this problem, and if they do, that's the particular answer I want. This is not really an opinion, it should be backed up by some citation from a SOLID OOP source, such as Uncle Bob, or one of his minions.

Comment: Per [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/64132), 'name that thing' questions are not necessarily bad.

Comment: You don't have to have a field ("Count") in each, only in one place. If the Count has some meaning to your domain, put it in CModelBox. If it is only relevant to the presentation, keep it in CViewBox.

Comment: Nice, and correct, and not what I want to know. Imagine I am in a code-review meeting or a design discussion meeting and I want to discuss the problem in depth.  I want to know what professional software developers call such problems, and thus I may find the resources I need to discuss remediating it.  I know the solution for trivial demos: Stop repeating state! Various barriers exist to clearing up that repeated state. The discussion of how to fix the problem may be aided by literature/books that discuss the anti-pattern (if it is one).

Comment: copypasta, inconsistency

Comment: that's just data consistency/synchronization. People might say it's DRY->Don't Repeat Yourself, but that's more about the code itself - don't repeat the same blocks of code. Often times you'll have a piece of data in a presentation layer, a model layer, and a persistence layer. The solution is people try to come up with automatic-data-binding techniques that automatically synchronizes those pieces of data, but most people would refer to it as just data synchronization.

Comment: This is a "name that thing" question where people can come up with all kinds of names and none are more correct than others, so it's not really answerable. Sorry, voting to close.

Comment: With regards to databases, the equivalent of DRY is [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).  Not sure if it can be applied to data in the code (free variables, object attributes, etc)

Comment: I think there is an arguably correct name. Third Normal Form is a DRY state for data. The name that will show up reliably in professional literature on development, architecture, and design-pattern texts.  Normalization (good, here) and Denormalization (here used in a deprecatory sense) is perhaps the CORRECT answer.  Since all live data (persisted or not) should be discussable via some kind of abstract but precise term, this is kind of a line-up of a small number of potential answers.

Comment: I have asked now for the question to be constrained to those answers which fit in with, or defined by those who follow the SOLID OOP (SRP, LSP, etc) principle set.

Answer (score 5):

I call this "redundancy".
Is redundancy good or bad?

It's good if it exists for the purpose of correcting errors,
*and* if there is a mechanism in place for correcting those errors.

It's bad if it's just "there", because of just what you describe.
It can get inconsistent, and then you're at sea.

One method that is sold as a technique to prevent the inconsistency is *notifications*.
I don't care for those, for a variety of reasons.

Rather, what I try to do is:

1. Minimize redundancy, so as to minimize the opportunity for inconsistency. This may mean sharing data, or something like that. This is the reason databases are "normalized".
2. When some redundancy is unavoidable, as it often is, understand how to deal with it.
   I first try to understand which representation is "the boss", so if different data structures disagree, I can tell which one to believe.
   Then, I always try to follow a policy of *tolerating inconsistency*.
   I try to have a method to reconcile differences where they occur.
   I tend to use algorithms like "merge" and "diff" to do this.
   This opposes the strategy of using notifications, but I find it is much more reliable and efficient.

P.S. As an example, a long time ago I stumbled on [*differential execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875909/23771) which is one way to manage redundancy between a program's state and its UI.

Comment: you prefer diff over change notification, big surprise there ;P +1 though because it's a good answer and your approach though unconventional makes a lot of sense in a lot of ways. (I'm an unruly fan of eventing/messaging myself but at least your approach of diffing is both consistent, simple, and far better than the more conventional inconsistent applications of random techniques people tend to use)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I use events at low frequency, like once in a while just do a regeneration, but for high frequency messages are just too likely to get dropped or duplicated. Plus, often they are self-cancelling like "insert X", then "oops, don't". Plus, notifications get buried in classes, and they can easily go wild, soaking up CPU.

Comment: I understand. I've actually looked over your differential execution concept a fairly bit after other posts you've made around here, and I believe I have a firm grasp on it. It's quite inventive and I do like it.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Thanks. I guess I'm a bit of an outlier sometimes, but I am impressed with the fact that there are some really talented and helpful people on these sites.

Answer (score -1):

"Wet."

More precisely, failure to "stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)."

Comment: Dry refers to repeating code. Often times people have data in their DB and their applications memory and maybe a remote cache also, this is normal and not a failure to be DRY. Failure to be DRY is when you copy some code from one class to another class to another class rather than creating a reused abstraction where that code lives once.

Comment: This comment lives in your web browser and SE's database. It's not a failure to be DRY that this data lives in those two places.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa [Not according to the authors of *The Pragmatic Programmer*](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html): *"Most people take DRY to mean you shouldn't duplicate code. That's not its intention. The idea behind DRY is far grander than that. DRY says that every piece of system knowledge should have one authoritative, unambiguous representation. (...) A system's knowledge is far broader than just its code. It refers to database schemas, test plans, the build system, even documentation."* Note that my web browser isn't part of SE's system.

Comment: Note that 'wet' has been retconned to mean 'Write Everything Twice', which I find quite appropriate.

Comment: @Doval that's interesting and new to me, also I couldn't disagree more with it. That's either poorly explained or totally irrational because *everyone* has data duplicated, the only thing you can *not* duplicate is the code that accesses the data, but data must be duplicated both for redundancy and communication. The idea of not having data in multiple places makes no sense at all. As soon as you read a piece of data you've duplicated it into wherever you read it to.

Comment: Single source of truth is something I'm familiar with but it means something different than don't duplicate - single source of truth means all replicas come from the same source. Mixing that concept into something named don't *repeat* yourself is totally confusing as it sounds like you should have a single source of truth and you should never replicate it anywhere- which makes zero sense.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Yes, well, "Single Source of Truth" doesn't quite roll off the tongue as well as DRY, and I've yet to find anyone who found the concept confusing. There's worse slogans, like "Code to an interface, not an implementation", which people *do* routinely misunderstand to mean "Code to an `interface`, not a `class`".

Comment: @Doval single source of truth and DRY are totally different concepts though... one says abstract code and don't copy-paste it, the other says have an authoritative source of data that all data can trace it's lineage to - and don't have two roots in that lineage tree. Claiming these under the same principle is really confusing...

Comment: @JimmyHoffa DRY is about knowledge duplication, not code duplication. See: http://verraes.net/2014/08/dry-is-about-knowledge/ . But I think you're misunderstanding the quote Doval posted. "Every piece of system knowledge" does not mean the data that the system operates on, so it would not include, for example, redundancy.

Comment: "In software engineering, don’t repeat yourself (DRY) is a principle of software development, aimed at reducing repetition of information of all kinds, especially useful in multi-tier architectures." -- [the Wikipedia entry for DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). The world is full of wetness, caches, copies, and overlaps. Doesn't make the general "stay DRY when you can" advice less useful.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Although the original question is about data, not system knowledge, so that may be the confusion (and probably why this answer was downvoted)

Comment: I like the "redundancy" answer better, but I think DRY still applies.  So upvoting both answers.

Comment: +1. I agree with the DRY usually meaning blocks of executable statements. I always use DRY to refer to blocks of repeated code. But then   "int FieldName;" repeated in various places is a line of code that is repeated,and so in a way, DRY also applies.

Comment: Terms like "redundancy," "caching," and "replicas" suggest intentional, planned copies of data for increased reliability, performance, scalability, etc. Yes they're copies and yes they can be out of sync/incoherent/temporally inconsistent. But they all are established mindfully, in full view of their tradeoffs.